# Problem in colors of multiple boxplot charts

Tags: colors, boxplot, enumerate

I want to create multiple boxplot chart from an excel file. my problem is taht all boxex gain same color (dark blue) however I did not define such color !
this is my code and it specified that what colors are I want:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the Excel file into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel('D:\Omid_TTU\RA\TASK5\selected1daybefore&after\GIS_Standard_format\FID_6_test2.xlsx')

# create a grid of subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=5, figsize=(20, 5))

# loop through each column and plot it in its own subplot
for i, col in enumerate(['Liq_depth_dim', 'TMP_air_temp', 'VIS_dist_dim', 'WND_dir_ang', 'WND_speed_rate']):
    data = df[col].dropna()
    axs[i].boxplot(data, patch_artist=True, notch=True, vert=False)
    axs[i].set_title(col)
    axs[i].set_yticklabels([])

    color_list = ['red', 'lightyellow', 'green', 'slateblue2', 'steelblue1']
    for patch, colormap in zip(axs[i].boxplot(data, patch_artist=True, notch=True, vert=False)['boxes'], color_list):
        patch.set_facecolor(colormap)

    for whisker in axs[i].boxplot(data, patch_artist=True, notch=True, vert=False)['whiskers']:
        whisker.set(color='r', linewidth=3, linestyle=':')

    for cap in axs[i].boxplot(data, patch_artist=True, notch=True, vert=False)['caps']:
        cap.set(color='r', linewidth=2)

    for median in axs[i].boxplot(data, patch_artist=True, notch=True, vert=False)['medians']:
        median.set(color='g', linewidth=3)

    for flier in axs[i].boxplot(data, patch_artist=True, notch=True, vert=False)['fliers']:
        flier.set(marker='D', color='r', alpha=0.5)

# adjust the spacing between subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)

plt.show()
```

could you please help me with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPzEw.png)

I want to create multiple boxplot chart from an excel file. my problem is taht all boxex gain same color (dark blue) however I did not define such color !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling axs[i].boxplot(...) inside the for loop while setting each of your settings like whisker, median, etc. as well as patch. This is creating a new boxplot each time. That is the reason it is not working. As I dont have your data, I am using seaborn provided titanic dataset and showcasing the right way for 3 variables. Note that you need to first assign the boxplot (created only once inside the FOR loop to `box` and then calling each of the properties within it. You can set this to your data and it should work fine. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the Excel file into a pandas dataframe
#df = pd.read_excel('D:\Omid_TTU\RA\TASK5\selected1daybefore&after\GIS_Standard_format\FID_6_test2.xlsx')
df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")  ## My titanic data

# create a grid of subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(20, 5)) ## Changed ncols to 3, make it 5 for your data

# loop through each column and plot it in its own subplot
#for i, col in enumerate(['Liq_depth_dim', 'TMP_air_temp', 'VIS_dist_dim', 'WND_dir_ang', 'WND_speed_rate']):
for i, col in enumerate(['age', 'fare', 'pclass']): ##Changed cols for titanic
    data = df[col].dropna()
    box=axs[i].boxplot(data, patch_artist=True, notch=True, vert=False) ##Assigned boxplot to box - do only once inside one FOR loop
    axs[i].set_title(col)
    axs[i].set_yticklabels([])

    color_list = ['red', 'lightyellow', 'green', 'slateblue2', 'steelblue1']

    for patch in box['boxes']:
        patch.set_facecolor(color_list[i]) ## Face color
    for whisker in box['whiskers']:
        whisker.set(color='r', linewidth=3, linestyle=':') 
    for cap in box['caps']:
        cap.set(color='r', linewidth=2)
    for median in box['medians']:
        median.set(color='g', linewidth=3)
    for flier in box['fliers']:
        flier.set(marker='D', color='r', alpha=0.5)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)

plt.show()
```

**Output plot**

[image]